# How to split a dictionary in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was wondering if there is a simple way, a built-in function to split a dictionary in javascript.

For example:

my dictionary is:

```
let data = {    "Is your salary above 1000$?":["yes","no",false,0],
              "Is your salary above 2000?":["yes","no",false,1],
              "Is your salary above 3000?":["yes","no",false,2],
              "Is your salary above 4000?":["yes","no",false,3],
              "Is your salary above 5000?":["yes","no",false,4]}
```

I want it to be:

```
 data1 = {    "Is your salary above 1000$?":["yes","no",false,0],
              "Is your salary above 2000?":["yes","no",false,1]}

 data2 = {     "Is your salary above 3000?":["yes","no",false,2],
              "Is your salary above 4000?":["yes","no",false,3],
              "Is your salary above 5000?":["yes","no",false,4]}
```

I can do it through looping but i was wondering if there is a faster way or a built in fuction, i did search but i didn't find anything that does that.

Comment: This is a JavaScript object, not a Dictionary

Comment: Based on what are you splitting it? What's the logic

Comment: I want to split it like slicing in python, not based on something specifically, let's say i want my 5 length object to be divided into 2 and 3 lengths object

Comment: @Abdel-Rahman Objects (dictionaries) don't have an order, so no. Use an array instead, you can `.slice()` that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [Object.entries(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)) to convert your object into an array of key-value pairs
- slice it using [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- Convert back every Array of key-value pairs back into an Object use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const data = {
  "Is your salary above 1000$?": ["yes", "no", false, 0],
  "Is your salary above 2000$?": ["yes", "no", false, 1],
  "Is your salary above 3000$?": ["yes", "no", false, 2],
  "Is your salary above 4000$?": ["yes", "no", false, 3],
  "Is your salary above 5000$?": ["yes", "no", false, 4],
};

const sliceAt = 2;
const dataArr = Object.entries(data);
const obA = Object.fromEntries(dataArr.slice(0, sliceAt));
const obB = Object.fromEntries(dataArr.slice(sliceAt));

console.log(obA);
console.log(obB);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.entries` to convert it to an array. Then use `splice` to divide it up. Then use `Object.fromEntries()` to convert the arrays back into objects.

```js
let data = {
  "Is your salary above 1000$?": ["yes", "no", false, 0],
  "Is your salary above 2000?": ["yes", "no", false, 1],
  "Is your salary above 3000?": ["yes", "no", false, 2],
  "Is your salary above 4000?": ["yes", "no", false, 3],
  "Is your salary above 5000?": ["yes", "no", false, 4]
}

const end = Object.entries(data);
const start = end.splice(0, 2); // Take two entries off the front of the array
const results = [start, end].map(Object.fromEntries);

console.log(results);
```